# How to use TFS in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, tfs

I'm using visual studio 2012 and want to save my work on TFS. I've created an an account on TFS and when I try to connect with TFS it is showing like this.

[image: Connecting Visual Studio 2012 with TFS]

I don't know how to commit my changes on TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a workspace on your local machine. Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that describes creating a workspace and checking in files.